# placement new equivalent in D2?

Tags: d

I want to construct an object in a specific location obtained from C's malloc. According to [this](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/learn/Placement_New_20402.html) thread, there was some equivalent to C++'s placement new in D1, but something about something may or may not have happened.

How do I invoke the constructor on the location obtained from malloc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [emplace](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#.emplace) from std.conv.